# Как из ссылки вытащить цифры с помощью regex?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Как из ссылки

```
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/thinc/275?ean=2940653896858
```

вытащить цифры после ean=

Работать нужно Java классами Pattern, Matcher. Что-то типа такого

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("ean=/только цифры, до первого символа/");
matcher = pattern.matcher(url.toString());
if (matcher.find()) {
    String ean = matcher.group().replace("ean=/только цифры, до первого символа/","");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\d+ же.

Comment: Pattern.compile("ean=/\\d+"); не помогло.
Как правильно?

Comment: Примерно так, результат в первой группе  

    Pattern.compile("\\bean=(\\d+)(?:$|\\D)"